# add a Horizontal Scrollbar in a comboBox for the long text dropdown items

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, combobox, actionscript

I have tried using `dropdownWidth` property, however it will be static. But if data is too long again i can't see the full text in the dropdown.

So my requirement is to set the `width` based on the long width of the text of the dropdown item either to set the horizontal scroll bar .

Since the flex does not support the horizontal scrolling , i override the Combobox class

```
<mx:FormItem id="zoneformitem" label="{Localizer.getString('zone','i18n')}" paddingLeft="60" paddingTop="15" required="true">
<mx:ComboBox id="selectedzone" open="campaigns.view.utils.CustomiZeCombo"
selectedIndex="-1" 
dropdownWidth="210" width="209" change="validateZoneSelection()" 
focusOut="validateZoneSelection()"
 dataProvider="{slotProxy.slotWizardVo.currentZones.source.
sortOn('zoneName')}" >
<mx:itemRenderer>
<mx:Component>


    public class CustomiZeCombo extends ComboBox{
    public function CustomiZeCombo(){
        super();
    }
    override public function open():void { 
        dropdown.horizontalScrollPolicy = ScrollPolicy.ON; 
        super.open(); 
    } 

override protected function 
       downArrowButton_buttonDownHandler(event:FlexEvent):void { 
        dropdown.horizontalScrollPolicy = ScrollPolicy.ON; 
        super.downArrowButton_buttonDownHandler(event); 
        } 
    }
```

But i am not getting how to call that event to make it work.
Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling the below method using click() even of Combobox.

```
 private function setWidthForLongdata():void {
        var width:int;
        width = selectedzone.width;
        var maxWidth:int;
        maxWidth = width + (width/2);

        for each (var zone:ZoneVO in slotProxy.slotWizardVo.currentZones.source) {
        if(zone.zoneName.length > maxLen ) {
        maxLen = zone.zoneName.length;
        }
        }

        if(maxLen*13 > width) {
        width = maxLen*13;

        if(width>maxWidth) {
        width = maxWidth;
        }
        }
        selectedzone.dropdown.width=width;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Avinash T S